# Building a messaging/chat system with ajax

Tags: ajax, data-modeling

I am having trouble building a database structure for an Online "user to user" messaging / chat system...

Most of the challenges I am facing lies in echoing out the messages , been styled to the appropriate position. Such that the messages float to the right if you are the sender, and Left if I am currently sending to you..

Here's my database structure .

```
message_id     #primary key
userid         #your id 
mwith          #id of the person your are messaging
seen
date
```

Comment: What does positioning the messages on the page have to do with database structure?

Answer (score 0):

You're not exactly specifying any concrete problem but if you want to align the text for sender and receiver, just use the concrete Stylye for your text component (based on your CSS) alingning the text accordingly for each style (left or right)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest changing `userid` and `mwith` to `sender` and  `receiver`.

```
.left {
    float: left;   
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Using these two css classes you can let the messages float either left or right.

For the database part:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE sender IN ('".$sender."', '".$receiver."')
AND receiver IN ('".$sender."', '".$receiver."')
ORDER BY date ASC
;
```

What you can now do is loop through these messages and check if the sender is you. If this is the case, add the `.left` class. If it is not, add the `.right` class.

I could go more in depth on creating a chat system but my answer would simply become to extensive.